# How to change cursor color in iphone's UISearchBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar

Is it possible to change color of cursor in `UISearchBar`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is possible in iOS 7. Simply set the tint color of your UISearchBar. So, for example, in your app delegate:

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

From what I can tell, this only affects the cursor color.

Comment: Wrong, the tintColor also applies to the "cancel"-button. Perhaps more elements. See my answer for a way to only apply tint to the Cursor.

Answer (score 5):

What you actually could do is this:

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UISearchBar class], nil] setTintColor:YOUR_COLOR_HERE];
```

If you want different tint for the searchbar itself.

Answer (score 1):

I created my own `SearchController` which extends `UISearchController` and
used the following code to use different colors for cursor and cancel button

```
self.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.greyColor()
self.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.greyColor()
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

For SWIFT 5

```
self.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.gray
self.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.gray
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 4 Example

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).tintColor = .lightGray
```

This will adjust the cursor to `UIColor.lightGray` without changing the cancel button color.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately not.  I would also like to use a custom font in the UISearchBar, but that's not possible either.

Comment: Wrong, try the following:

for (UIView *subView in _searchBar.subviews) {
    if ([subView isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]]) {
        [(UITextField *)subView setFont:myFont];
    }
}

Answer (score -1):

Although it may, somehow, be possible to override the entire UISearchBar class, Apple will not accept any apps that change their classes. If it is really necessary, then you could create your own searchbar. Seems like a lot of work for cursor color though.